# Using Past Cont instead of Past Perf Cont

Tags: past-tense, past-continuous, past-perfect-continuous

I have the sentence: "The youngsters had been playing in the backyard of the home, digging in the mud, when they found something unusual just below the surface." How would the meaning here change, if I said "were playing" instead of "had been playing"?

Comment: Please edit to tell about what you already know about past simple vs perfect. The meaning would change in line with what those tenses do. If we can make the confusion more clear we can get a better answer.

Comment: _Were playing_ would be used if the narrative was about the moment of finding the 'something'. _Had been playing_ suggests that the finding was in the past, and the story may go on to describe what has happened since then.

Comment: @KateBunting - I came to post that as an answer, but you've already done so as a comment.  Now what?  :P

Comment: @Seattleguy - You are welcome to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Kate Bunting concisely commented:

*Were playing* would be used if the narrative was about the moment of finding the 'something'. *Had been playing* suggests that the finding was in the past, and the story may go on to describe what has happened since then.